# JavaScript using atom , gives error when using es6 classes

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, es6-class

[a link to the tutorial,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puWqNBFDMMk&index=8&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh)
[this is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql2Gw.png)

So i'm trying to follow along with the coding trains neural network series, using p5.js on atom, in Ep 10 of the series, coding train updates the Matrix algebra code to es6, when I follow along with this I get the error listed above, since the code is shown to work in the tutorial video I assume the error is in how iv set up atom, btw before switching to es6 syntax the code ran fine just using functions not classes. Iv tried switching to babel as the grammar used but this makes no difference. Has anyone else tried following this tutorial? How did u set everything up to get it to work? Thanks for any help.

(if anyone asks iv triple checked that its copied correctly from the tutorial)

Here's all the code.

```
class Matrix{
Constructor(rows,cols){

this.rows=rows;
this.cols=cols;
this.matrix=[];

for(let i =0;i<this.rows;i++){
this.matrix[i]=[];
for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++){
this.matrix[i][j]=0;
}
}

randomize(){
for(let i =0;i<this.rows;i++){
for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++){
this.matrix[i][j]+=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}}}}}
```

Edit: was just a dumb mistake, solved now thanks for responses.

Comment: Please add the actual code that generates the error and not just an image of it.  There may be a mistake.  Please also link to the relevant tutorial.  The code in your image has an error because it should be `function randomize(){}` not just `randomize()`.  You are declaring a function.

Comment: @zero298 Thanks have added the code and link to video, they definately dont write function randomize in the tutorial, tried it anyway and it removed the error however now when i execute randomize on a matrix i get type error randomize is not a function. I type let x = new Matrix(3,3); then x.randomize(); then i get the type error.

Comment: Please don't use tags that are irrelevant to the question. I have removed the `atom-editor`, since the editor is not part of the problem.

Comment: Please indent your code properly - it may as well help to localise the mistake. Btw, `constructor` needs to be spelled lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error would be more obvious if you formatted your code better (e.g. use [Prettier](https://prettier.io)). You have misplaced one of the closing curly braces: there's one missing in your constructor function and one too many at the end of your code.

Here's what the code is supposed to look like:

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.matrix = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
      this.matrix[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
        this.matrix[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  randomize() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
        this.matrix[i][j] += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to put the function inside the constructor. You have to declare it outside the constructor but inside the class like shown below
also like mentioned in the comment above constructor should be lowercase:

```
class Matrix{

  constructor(rows,cols){
    this.rows=rows;
    this.cols=cols;
    this.matrix=[];

    for(let i =0;i<this.rows;i++){
      this.matrix[i]=[];
      for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++){
        this.matrix[i][j]=0;
      }
    }
  }



  randomize(){
    for(let i =0;i<this.rows;i++){
      for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++){
          this.matrix[i][j]+=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And yes you don't need the "function" inside a class. Check this out https://javascript.info/class